# How do I reset Chrome's "Open link with" setting?

Tags: google-chrome

I clicked a link in a site that would open an external app. I want this. However, I accidentally clicked "Don't open", and the "Don't ask me again" checkbox was checked. Now, I don't know how to get that link to work.

**Is there any way I can 'uncheck' that box and get the link to work again?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Goto URL `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` 
2) Select duration "Past week". 
3) Select only "Cookies and other site data"
4) Click "Clear Browsing Data" and browse site again.

**For Chrome Canary (It will be available in upcoming versions of chrome)**
0) Go to website.

1) In the address bar click on the "i" symbol (HTTP site) or green pad lock symbol (HTTPS) site.

2) Click on "Site Settings".

3) Click on "Reset site settings" at the bottom and click reset.

Comment: When I click "Site Settings", I get this: https://i.imgur.com/qv3XjOF.png; no reset to be found

Comment: Actually I'm using Chrome Canary which has this option. https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: so... Your solution is for me to wait up to 6 months to hopefully get the update that's currently in the nightly build?

Comment: Try this: Goto chrome://settings/clearBrowserData   Select duration "Past week". Then select only "Cookies and other site data". Click "Clear Browsing Data"

Comment: That last suggestion worked!

Comment: It's been a few years and I assume that what you saw as Canary eventually made it to the public release. Is this now what Chrome calls "Reset permissions"? "Clear data"?

Comment: I'm not sure what was in Canary release in 2017 but the "Reset permissions" does not work, I had to clear "Cookies and other site data" from All Time in order to reset that permission for MS Teams.